# Is there a standard way to detect directional character?

Tags: java, character

I'm parsing a text file made from this [Wikipedia article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_park), basically I made a <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and copy/paste all the content in a text file. (I use it as example).
I'm trying to make a list of words with their counts and for that I use a Scanner with this delimiter :

```
    sc.useDelimiter("[\\p{javaWhitespace}\\p{Punct}]+");
```

It works great for my need, but analysing the result, I saw something that looks like a blank token ([again...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10765597/1140748)). The character is after `(nynorsk)‬` in the article (funny when I copy/paste here the character disappear, in gedit I can use <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd> and the cursor don't move).

After further research I've found out that this token was actually the [POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (U+202C)](http://www.charbase.com/202c-unicode-pop-directional-formatting).

It's not the only directional character, looking at the [Character documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) Java seems to define them.

***So I'm wondering if there is a standard way to detect these characters, and if possible a way that can be easily integrated in the delimiter pattern***.

I'd like to avoid to make my own list because I fear I will forgot some of them.

Comment: Don't those characters actually control how the following text is to be interpreted? Are you sure it's a good idea to just throw that information away?

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes in this particular case I don't need it, I'm looking for statistics only so the text flow doesn't matter.

Comment: Fair enough, just wanted to mention it :)

Comment: You do great because it gives me an idea for an other part of my work ;)

Comment: What about just going the other way round and using `[^\p{L}]+` as the delimiter?

Comment: That seems strange.. Shouldn't the inverse of `\p{L}` be a subset of both `\p{javaWhitespace}` and `\p{Punct}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always go the other way round and use a whitelist rather than a blacklist:

```
sc.useDelimiter("[^\\p{L}]+");
```

Comment: Works great thanks, I do not have to use `\\p{javaWhitespace}\\p{Punct}` anymore you're right.