# 'String Index out of Range' Error Message in Java using charAt

Tags: java, exception, char, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

Recently, while coding I came upon the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
                     String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at TestAssign2.main(TestAssign2.java:119)
```

The error appears when I add the line - `firstLetter=userName.charAt(0);` to the code and program displays the error message after the user enters all the values asked. Before this line was entered, it all worked fine.

```
while(uProgStart.equals(PROGSTART))
        {


            System.out.println("What is your name?");
            userName=sc.nextLine();
            junk = sc.nextLine();



            System.out.println("What is the year of your birth?");
            birthYear = sc.nextInt();
            junk = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is the date of your birth? (dd.mm)");
            birthDDMM = sc.nextDouble();
            junk = sc.nextLine();



            day=(int)birthDDMM;

            month=(int)Math.round(100*birthDDMM)%100;

                //Begins calculation of Dss Score
                if(birthYear%CYCLE_LENGTH!=SNAKE_YEAR)
                    {
                        DssScore=DssScore+1;
                    }

                if(month<SPRING_BEGINNING||month>SPRING_END)

                    {
                        DssScore=DssScore+2;
                    }

     firstLetter=userName.charAt(0);            
            if(firstLetter==(LOWER_S)||firstLetter==(UPPER_S))
                {
                    DssScore=DssScore+4;
                }
```

The idea of the line was to see if the name entered by the user begins with either the letter 's' or 'S'.

All the variables have been declared, I just haven't included them for the sake of keeping this post a little succinct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are pressing enter key by mistake without giving a chance to enter any input and it forces username variable be empty. I reproduced this error like mentioned above.Sometime when you deal with `scanner`, it happens like that.

So in your code, check whether the `username` is null or not before doing any operation.

Comment: Ta UVM. I have made sure that the user can enter a string (their name) and the error persists. Here is an example of the program's output:**What is your name?** Sam **What is the year of your birth?** 1994 **What is the date of your birth? (dd.mm)** 26.11 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)

Comment: can you paste youe complete code? and try changin the sequence like this: System.out.println("What is your name?");      
junk = sc.nextLine();
userName=sc.nextLine();

Comment: I have found the problem. The string userName is indeed empty and the name the user enters is instead stored in junk variable (rather than the enter as I intended). Thanks for the advice for a stupid mistake. @Kirby

Answer (score 0):

The call to `sc.nextLine()` for assigning `userName` prior to the charAt call likely returns an empty string (eg. if you scan a blank line).

Comment: So would you recommend moving the charAt line above `userName=sc.nextLine();`?

Comment: Well, the OP doesn't show how the scanner is initialized, but the point of userName=sc.nextLine() is to retrieve the username, right?  Currently, I would bet that sc.nextLine() is returning an empty string, so you're not getting the username you want.  In a file, for example, this might happen if you are scanning a newline.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765597/understanding-usedelimiter-in-scanner-why-i-get-blank-token

Comment: My hunch is that the call to sc.nextLine() is getting a blank token there, so you're not reading the value you want.

Comment: Your right about userName=sc.nextLine(). However,this is what the program looks like when it is run: `What is your name?
Sam
What is the year of your birth?
1994
What is the date of your birth? (dd.mm)
26.11
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
 at TestAssign2.main(TestAssign2.java:148)`                    So the String userName shouldn't be empty.

Comment: You could just make a loop with two checks:
while(sc.hasNextLine() && (userName = sc.nextLine()).equals(""))

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `if` to make sure that the next line really exists.

Something like this:

```
if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
   userName = sc.nextLine()
} else {
  System.out.println("OMG... Where is my line?")
}
```

This most likely not a good fix for your problem, but based on the limited information we have it's difficult to suggest anything better.

The real problem is most likely elsewhere in your logic.